# My file sharing app does not conect to Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, google-play-services

The config file `google-services.json` is present in my code, but it indicates a project ID "studentfilesharing" that you don't have access to.

Do I need to request access or delete the file in order to proceed with the connection process?

But both the Gmail in android studio and on Firebase are same.

Comment: Have you implemented the FIrebase Auth in your app ? If not then either you should implement that or change the default security rules in the firebase console from realtime database tab as read and write to true !

Comment: do make sure you downloaded the json file from correct project.

Answer (score 0):

You already said that you don't have access to that project so delete the old JSON file and download a new one from your project console